# A segmentation fault that won't allow me to access a public variable

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program that is supposed to simulate a library and in one of the functions I faced a segmentation fault and I don't see why it won't work.

```
void add()
{
    Book* newBook = new Book;
    Book* temp = new Book;
    temp = head;
    string tempstring;
    int id;
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the ID of the book you wanna add: ";
    cin >> id;
```

in the if condition below will check if the linkedlist is empty or not and just add the book and get out of the function

```
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        newBook->id = id;
        cout << "Enter the name of the Book: ";
        cin >> tempstring;
        newBook->nameOfTheBook = tempstring;
        cout << "Enter the Name of the Author: ";
        cin >> tempstring;
        newBook->author = tempstring;
        cout << "Enter The number of copys you're going to add: ";
        cin >> n;
        newBook->numOfBooks += n;

        newBook->next = NULL;
        head = newBook;
        return;
    }
```

here is where I have the error in the if condition if(temp->id == id)

```
if(

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->id == id)
        {
            temp->numOfBooks += 1;
            if(temp->avaliable == 0)
            temp->avaliable = 1;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    newBook->id = id;
    cout << "Enter the name of the Book: ";
    cin >> tempstring;
    newBook->nameOfTheBook = tempstring;
    cout << "Enter the Name of the Author: ";
    cin >> tempstring;
    newBook->author = tempstring;
    cout << "Enter The number of copys you're going to add: ";
    cin >> n;
    newBook->numOfBooks += n;
```

here the value of temp should be NULL and I replaced the temp with the newBook

```
    newBook->prev = temp->prev;
    newBook->next = NULL;
    temp->prev->next = newBook;

    newBook->avaliable = 1;   
}
```

Comment: `Book* temp = new Book;  temp = head;` -- Instant memory leak.  You are throwing away the value returned by `new` by overwriting `temp`.

Comment: *I'm writing a program that is supposed to simulate a library* -- It looks more like you are trying to write a program to maintain a home-made linked list.  If the goal was to simulate a library, you would just use `std::list<Book>` and thus get further writing the "library simulator".

Comment: yes that's true the goal isn't to simulate a library but rather to maintain the linked list

Comment: You may wish to add the definition of `Book`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters this code snippet in the function beginning

```
    Book* newBook = new Book;
    Book* temp = new Book;
    temp = head;
```

produces a memory leak. An object of the type `Book` was dynamically allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `temp` and then the pointer `temp` was reassigned. So the allocated object is lost.

And there is also one more memory leak. The allocated dynamically object of the type `Book`

```
    Book* newBook = new Book;
```

can be unused due to the `return` statement in this if statement

```
        if(temp->id == id)
        {
            temp->numOfBooks += 1;
            if(temp->avaliable == 0)
            temp->avaliable = 1;
            return;
        }
```

And again the allocated object will be lost.

As for the program crash then after the while loop

```
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->id == id)
        {
            temp->numOfBooks += 1;
            if(temp->avaliable == 0)
            temp->avaliable = 1;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

the pointer `temp` is equal to `NULL`. So using the null pointer in this code snippet

```
    newBook->prev = temp->prev;
    newBook->next = NULL;
    temp->prev->next = newBook;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Also when `head` is equal to `NULL` then the data member `prev` of the created node is not set to `NULL` (`nullptr`).

You need to redesign the function.